# PayPal recommendation Please

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

We have developing an application that will be "pay per use"
Every time a user logs on, their "User token license" is decremented by 1 unit.
When the "User Token License" is zero, the user can no longer access the software until they purchase more "User Tokens"
We wish to use Paypal to take payment from within the application and once payment has been processed, update the "User Token License" table within the application Database.

Can someone recommend the best way to do this and what api options are best to use ?

Regards

Si

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Express Checkout API's](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/overview-ec.pdf) for the payment processing and [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) for updating the database when payments are completed.

If you're working with PHP my [class library](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make the API calls very simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal offers 3 integration types:
1. [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) (the most common)
2. [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)
3. [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)

The description of your requirement is that of a recurring payment, without a predefined period. This means that you cannot tell PayPal to charge $X every month. Therefore, Option #1 is ruled out.
Both *Adaptive Payments* and *PayPal Payments Pro* offer recurring charges with dynamic periods and amounts, but require PayPal's approval and quite a bit of paperwork. If you're approved, the APIs are pretty simple in both cases.

May I suggest some easier alternatives?
1. Every time the user runs out of tokens, send him to PayPal Express checkout for a new purchase (he will have to manually do this, the payment can't be automated on your end)
2. Use [Recurly](https://recurly.com/) who are already approved for #2 above (adaptive payments)
3. Change your pricing policy to a monthly charge of $X, granting a set of tokens. The user can upgrade to a higher plan to get more tokens every month.